# Troubleshooting Boolean Issues

Tags: modifiers

Blender 2.90.1

I'm relatively new to blender, only have been using it and following tutorials for a couple months. Typically, with enough research I can solve whatever issue or mistake I come across, but countless google searches and this one still eludes me.

Currently I am following Derek Elliot's phone product animation video where he begins modeling a phone, adds a couple bevels and a solidify modifier for the body, then duplicates it retaining the modifiers (excluding the 2nd bevel) to create the port and buttons on the outer edge of the phone before applying a boolean to those intersecting buttons so that they cut out shapes from the phone body.

When I initially followed this method, my phone became "hollow" with the 'eyedropped' shapes just becoming transparent when set to bounds. (or wire.) I dug through the comments for tips but found nothing, moved to google and forum searching where there were similar problems, but none that solved mine. (manifold problems etc.)

I began to just try some trial and error within blender and have discovered:

- Default cube resized functions (mostly) properly with a boolean.
- Duplicated phone mesh with phone modifiers (tutorial video) did not work regardless of placement.
- Separately modeled port shape works only when intersecting the top face of the phone.
- Modeling the phone at both life size scale and fictional large scale produced the same problems.

Issue *seems* to come from straying too far from a default mesh. Too many vertices?
[image: hollow phone]

[image: boolean working better on top face]

[image: modifier info]

[image: default cube boolean]

[image: custom shape vertices]

[image: phone body vertices]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and am in a similar situation to you (in that I'm relatively new). I believe the solution ended up being checking where I shade smooth and manually changing the geometry so I didn't get any weird artifacts. If I remember correctly, the issue is with the two meshes having different geometry, so blender struggles to match them in a pleasing way.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it, I'll look into what I can do with the geometry.